# How to serve a django-webodt file to users?

Tags: django

I'm trying to allow users to export some of their database data. I am using django-webodt to create a .odt file from their data. I then am trying to allow them to download it. The file is created just fine, but when it downloads it seems to download a blank file. I think there is some difference between where the server is looking for the file and where it actually is. I was wondering how to get this to work properly? I'm relatively new to django so any help would be appreciated. The code I have is below:

```
def downloadBook(request, val):
    template = webodt.ODFTemplate('conversion.odt')
    context = dict(ideas=Book.objects.getIdeaSet(int(val)))
    document = template.render(Context(context))
    file_name = os.path.basename(document.name)
    path_to_file = os.path.dirname(document.name)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
    response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_str(path_to_file)
    return response
```

Comment: I think the correct mimetype is application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text

Comment: Is your query mistyped? Shouldn't it be context = dict(ideas=Book.objects.get(IdeaSet = int(val)))

Comment: Ulmer, the query is fine, and gets the right data. I am using a manager and have defined a function getIdeaSet.

Comment: Victor Castillo Torres, changing the mimetype didn't result in any positive effect.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it works:

```
from django.template import Context
from webodt import ODFTemplate

template = ODFTemplate('template_file.odt')
context = { 'some_dict': '' }
document = template.render(Context(context))
response = HttpResponse(document.read(), mimetype='application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text')
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=fancy-filename-as-you-like.odt"
document.close() # delete the document on /tmp
return response
```